# JQuery ajax not sending full data in POST in case data is big

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, electron

In my application, I am calling an API with POST type using jquery $.ajax function. When data is big then it is truncating part of the data. But when I am sending same data using POSTMAN then it is working fine and the server is getting the full request. Issue is coming only when I am calling the API in javascript using Jquery. My application is built in Electron.  Below is the code for the API call:

```
$.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: 'API_URL_HERE',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': authToken,
                },
                data: {
                    var1: "123456789",
                    var2: 10,
                    var3: {
                        'var3_data': array_containing_strings,
                        'var3_version': 20
                    },
                    var4: 80,
                    var5: "123456789"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                        // Some operation here
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        // Some operation here
                }
});
```

I have renamed the variable names. Issue is in **array_containing_strings** variable. It is an array which contains strings. When array_containing_strings contains so many strings then the server is not receiving **var4** and **var5** variables. I tried with the array of length 13000 while each element of the array is String of length 400 characters(so size = 13000 * 400 = 5200000). Strangely data sent to the server is valid JSON format, only variables are missing in the request. One more strange thing is that when I am opening the network tab in the developer console, then it is showing full data in network call the only server is not receiving it. Server configuration also seems not be the issue as same API call with same data is working fine when using Postman.

Comment: maybe server is rejecting too big requests?

Comment: _"When data is big then it is truncating part of the data"_, how did you determine it is truncating? If JSON gets truncated it won't be parseable, so the server wouldn't have been able to decode the sent JSON.

Comment: Are you seriously sending such requests with `async: false`? I mean, you can do whatever you want, but... urgh.

Comment: _“when I am opening the network tab in the developer console, then it is showing full data in network call the only server is not receiving it”_ - pretty obvious that it _can not_ be the fault of your client-side code then, wouldn’t you say?

Comment: @stetoc It does not seem to be the server issue as same request working fine with Postman

Comment: @CBroe, my thought were also same that it should not client-side issue but when we checked the request on server-side, data was missing but when tried same thing with Postman then server receiving the full request.

Answer (score 1):

> add  **dataType:'json'** and **contentType:'application/json'** to yuor
>   ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'API_URL_HERE',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': authToken,
                    },
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType:'application/json'
                    data: {
                        var1: "123456789",
                        var2: 10,
                        var3: {
                            'var3_data': array_containing_strings,
                            'var3_version': 20
                        },
                        var4: 80,
                        var5: "123456789"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                            // Some operation here
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            // Some operation here
                    }
    });
```

Comment: should be `contentType: ...`

Comment: jQuery uses dataType to define ContentType.

Comment: not working anyways